# Outofbounds exception on empty ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm getting an outofbounds exception from the following code:

```
myArray.get(myArray.size() -  1)
```

I know it's due to the fact that `myArray` contains no items. I tried adding this before checking for the last added item in the array:

```
If (myArray.size()  == -1){ myArray.add(string) }
```

But that didn't make any difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think `size()` returns `-1` when it's empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
if (!myArray.isEmpty())
    myArray.get(myArray.size() -  1);
```

This will get the last value in the list, when the list isn't empty.

Answer (score 1):

`myArray.size()` will never be `-1`. Note that `size` is a non-negative number. It can be 0 or more.

You can check if it equals `0` and then add element.

Comment: I was under the impression that the first position in the array is 0, that's why I was checking for -1.

Comment: @Josh The first position in the array *is* 0, but the numbering scheme of the elements has no bearing on the total number of elements. The size of an empty array is 0 because there are 0 things in it. End of.